# Wget: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received

Tags: linux, networking, curl, download, wget

I'm trying to download pages : http://www.aliexpress.com/item/-/1947469066.html and others the same. Wget fails with the error "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.". Curl also generates an error : "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". Wget makes several attempts to download and sometimes it download  file. What might be the case?

Comment: Could you include the result of `curl -v YOURURL`? Thanks

Comment: sad that the OP never returned..

```
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* Connected to X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X) port YYYY (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: X.X.X.X:YYYY
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host X.X.X.X left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```